# How to hide certain tags from the_tags() in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I need to assign some tags to my posts (for external use), but I don't want them showing anywhere that tags are listed. Can someone please give me an example as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [get_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) instead of the_tags() in your templates

```
 $tags = get_tags();

 foreach ($tags as $tag)
 {
   if($tag->name=='the tag i want gone') continue;// do this for every tag you want gone
   echo $tag->name.', ';  
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error for line "echo $tag;". Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

this question is very old but i came across this need and i found an interesting solution that i wanted to share.

It is better to apply a filter to the tags and you won't be afraid of missing points in your template where you show tags.

```
function exclude_tags($tags) {
 foreach ($tags as $tag)
  switch ($tag->name) {
   case 'exclude-this-tag':
   case 'exclude-this-tag-too':
    break;
   default:
    $newtags[] = $tag;
 }
 return $newtags;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_tags', 'exclude_tags');
```

Comment: For me it was `the_tags` filter. My theme use "the_tags" function.